# Highcharts exporting background image with chart?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

Here is my HighCharts chart code:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                type: 'bubble',
                renderTo: 'graph',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                events: {
                    load: function() {
                        this.renderer.image(backgroundImageURL, 230, 55, 720, 720).add(); // add image(url, x, y, w, h)
                    }
                },
                height: 788
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bubble: {
                    color: 'white',
                    marker: {
                        fillColor: 'transparent'
                    },
                    // minSize: 100,
                    // maxSize: 700,
                    // zMin: 0,
                    // zMax: 100
                },
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            mouseOver: function(event) {
                                $('.rankings-column').find('span').removeClass('selected');
                                if (!this.selected) {
                                    $('span#' + this.id).addClass('selected');

                                }
                                var donorrank = $('span#' + this.id).attr('id');
                                $report.html(donorrank + '. ' + this.name + ' <span>' + this.score + '%</span>');
                                $report.addClass('active');
                            },
                            mouseOut: function(event) {
                                $('.rankings-column span').each(function() {
                                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                                });
                                $report.removeClass('active');
                                $report.html('Donor Scoring');
                            },
                            click: function(event) {
                                if (!this.selected) {
                                    window.open(this.url, '_self');
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },

            yAxis: {
                gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                lineColor: 'transparent',
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                min: 0
                ,max: 100
            },
            xAxis: {

                gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                lineColor: 'transparent',
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                offset: 0,
                margin: 0
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                data: dataForChart
            }]
        });
```

backgroundImageURL is a JS var being passed through from the PHP page on which the chart displays.

This is in Worpress.  Here is the PHP for that:

```
$styleSheetURI = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
$backgroundImageURL = $styleSheetURI.'/img/ATI-graphs-main.png';
```

Here is how I turn it into a JS var:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        backgroundImageURL = <?php print(json_encode($backgroundImageURL)); ?>;
    });
</script>
```

Here is the php echo:

```
http://www.thewebsite.org/wp-content/themes/ati/img/ATI-graphs-main.png
```

It alerts exactly the same from JS

The export works, but the image is not included.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Jacques

Comment: How did you include the Highcharts code? External JS file? Your question is not clear on that part..

Comment: Yes it is an external JS file that is being included in the PHP file.

Comment: Have you tried alerting backgroundImageURL from that JS file?

Comment: <script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/explore-data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Yes, it alerts perfectly: http://www.thewebsite.org/wp-content/themes/ati/img/ATI-graphs-main.png

Comment: The link doesn't work

Comment: Your link to image requires to be public, but this one (http://www.thewebsite.org/wp-content/themes/ati/img/ATI-graphs-main.png) seems to be down. As a result it is not exported.

Comment: The link is Pseudo, since I do not want to expose the client url yet.  Rest assured that the image url is 100% correct.

Comment: Ok so how we can replicate this issue?

Comment: It's not that I need you to replicate it.  I want to know whether I am doing something wrong, assuming the images etc are correct.